# How do I get text containing a certain string between tags

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Please help me out with preg_match, I can't figure it out :(

I have a lot of text but I need to capture everything between "&" that contains a certain text.

example

```
"thisip4:isatextexample&ineed.thistext&TXT:&andthis.idontneed&txt:&test.thistext&"
```

I need to extract the complete text between & containing thistext

the result should be : `ineed.thistext`
AND : `test.thistext`

Many many many thanks in advance :)

oh I've tried using this;

```
&([^\\n]*thistext[^\\n]*)&
```

but that will not work with multiple '&'

W

Comment: ive tried a bunch, one that is close is "&([^\\n]*thistext[^\\n]*)&"

Comment: So, the right tag is not `preg-match`, but `preg-match-all`. Please retag and add `regex` and `php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern contains `[^\n]*` that matches any 0+ chars other than newlines, and that makes the regex engine match across any `&` chars greedily and find the last `&` on the line.

You may use

```
'~&([^&]*?thistext[^&]*)&~'
```

Then, grab Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1NNkbC/2).

**Details**

- `&` - a `&` char
- `([^&]*?thistext[^&]*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^&]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `&`, as few as possible
  - `thistext` - literal text
  - `[^&]*` - any 0+ chars other than `&`, as many as possible
- `&` - a `&` char

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ZdFKO):

```
$str = 'thisip4:isatextexample&ineed.thistext&TXT:&andthis.idontneed&txt:&test.thistext&';
if (preg_match_all('~&([^&]*?thistext[^&]*)&~', $str, $m)) {
    print_r($m[1]);
}
// => Array ( [0] => ineed.thistext [1] => test.thistext )
```

Comment: thanks a bunch :) but what if there are more instances of 'thistext' between & ? I need to grab them all

Comment: @user1973842 Show an example string with expected matches.

Comment: "thisip4:isatextexample&ineed.thistext&TXT:&andthis.idontneed&txt:&test.thistext&"

Comment: @user1973842 It is late here, I am a bit slow. `preg_match_all` will do the job.